# Need help adding a second y axis to my graph using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I need to add a Y axis on the right hand side of my graph showing frequency of occurrence but I am not sure how to make the frequency show up on the right hand side.

I was thinking I could just create a vector with the frequencies and pass that through `scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis())`. I am having a hard time figuring out how to do this and I know there needs to be a formula but I want the frequencies to line up with each bar graph and the corresponding names.

```
p<- ggplot(B, aes(Analytes, Concentration, ylab="Analyte"), na.rm=TRUE)

p + geom_boxplot(fill= "gray", na.rm=TRUE) + coord_flip() +
  geom_point(aes(color = Analyte)) + 
scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(?, name = "Frequency"))


B

             Analyte Concentration   MRL units Quarter Year             Source  X X.1   X.2
1                               NA    NA                 NA                    NA  NA    NA
2       Acesulfame-K     0.1200000 1e-02  µg/L    1st  2018                raw NA  NA    NA
3       Acesulfame-K     0.0800000 1e-02  µg/L    1st  2018     finished - WTF NA  NA    NA
4       Acesulfame-K     0.0700000 1e-02  µg/L    1st  2018 finished - rechlor NA  NA    NA
5       Acesulfame-K     0.1200000 1e-02  µg/L    2nd  2018                raw NA  NA    NA
6       Acesulfame-K     0.1200000 1e-02  µg/L    2nd  2018     finished - WTF NA  NA    NA
7       Acesulfame-K     0.0600000 1e-02  µg/L    2nd  2018 finished - rechlor NA  NA    NA
8       Acesulfame-K     0.0600000 1e-02  µg/L    3rd  2018                raw NA  NA    NA
9       Acesulfame-K     0.0600000 1e-02  µg/L    3rd  2018     finished - WTF NA  NA    NA
10      Acesulfame-K     0.1600000 1e-02  µg/L    3rd  2018 finished - rechlor NA  NA    NA
11      Acesulfame-K     0.0600000 1e-02  µg/L    4th  2018                raw NA  NA    NA
12      Acesulfame-K     0.0600000 1e-02  µg/L    4th  2018     finished - WTF NA  NA    NA
13      Acesulfame-K     0.0200000 1e-02  µg/L    4th  2018 finished - rechlor NA  NA    NA
14      Acesulfame-K     0.1200000 1e-02  µg/L    1st  2017                raw NA  NA    NA
15      Acesulfame-K     0.1100000 1e-02  µg/L    1st  2017     finished - WTF NA  NA    NA
16      Acesulfame-K     0.1500000 1e-02  µg/L    2nd  2017                raw NA  NA    NA
17      Acesulfame-K     0.1700000 1e-02  µg/L    2nd  2017     finished - WTF NA  NA    NA
18      Acesulfame-K     0.6900000 1e-02  µg/L    2nd  2017 finished - rechlor NA  NA    NA
19      Acesulfame-K     0.1100000 1e-02  µg/L    3rd  2017                raw NA  NA    NA
20      Acesulfame-K     0.1100000 1e-02  µg/L    3rd  2017     finished - WTF NA  NA    NA
21      Acesulfame-K     0.0400000 1e-02  µg/L    3rd  2017 finished - rechlor NA  NA    NA
22      Acesulfame-K     0.1200000 1e-02  µg/L    4th  2017                raw NA  NA    NA
23      Acesulfame-K     0.1000000 1e-02  µg/L    4th  2017     finished - WTF NA  NA    NA
24      Acesulfame-K     0.0200000 1e-02  µg/L    4th  2017 finished - rechlor NA  NA    NA
25      Acesulfame-K     0.1300000 1e-02  µg/L    3rd  2016     finished - WTF NA  NA    NA
26      Acesulfame-K     0.0900000 1e-02  µg/L    3rd  2016 finished - rechlor NA  NA    NA
27      Acesulfame-K     0.1300000 1e-02  µg/L    4th  2016                raw NA  NA    NA
28      Acesulfame-K     0.1000000 1e-02  µg/L    4th  2016     finished - WTF NA  NA    NA
29      Acesulfame-K     0.4100000 1e-02  µg/L    4th  2016 finished - rechlor NA  NA    NA
30      Acesulfame-K     0.1300000 1e-02 µg/L2    3rd  2016                raw NA  NA 1e-02
31          Atenolol     0.0020000 1e-03  µg/L    1st  2010                raw NA  NA    NA
32          Atenolol     0.0040000 1e-03  µg/L    1st  2010     finished - WTF NA  NA    NA
33          Atenolol     0.0040000 1e-03  µg/L    1st  2010 finished - rechlor NA  NA    NA
34          Atenolol     0.0050000 1e-03  µg/L    2nd  2010                raw NA  NA    NA
35          Atenolol     0.0050000 1e-03  µg/L    2nd  2010     finished - WTF NA  NA    NA
36          Atenolol     0.0050000 1e-03  µg/L    2nd  2010 finished - rechlor NA  NA    NA
37   Chloramphenicol     0.0130000 5e-03  µg/L    3rd  2014     finished - WTF NA  NA    NA
38  cis-Testosterone     0.5000000 1e-01  ng/L    1st  2018                raw NA  NA 1e-04
39  cis-Testosterone     0.3000000 1e-01  ng/L    1st  2018     finished - WTF NA  NA 1e-04
40  cis-Testosterone     1.4000000 1e-01  ng/L    1st  2016                raw NA  NA 1e-04
41  cis-Testosterone     0.7000000 1e-01  ng/L    1st  2016     finished - WTF NA  NA 1e-04
42  cis-Testosterone     0.4000000 1e-01  ng/L    2nd  2016                raw NA  NA 1e-04
43  cis-Testosterone     0.3000000 1e-01  ng/L    2nd  2016 finished - rechlor NA  NA 1e-04
44  cis-Testosterone     0.2000000 1e-01  ng/L    1st  2015                raw NA  NA 1e-04
45  cis-Testosterone     0.2000000 1e-01  ng/L    1st  2015     finished - WTF NA  NA 1e-04
46  cis-Testosterone     0.4000000 1e-01  ng/L    1st  2014                raw NA  NA 1e-04
47  cis-Testosterone     0.9000000 1e-01  ng/L    1st  2014     finished - WTF NA  NA 1e-04
48  cis-Testosterone     0.5000000 1e-01  ng/L    1st  2013                raw NA  NA 1e-04
49  cis-Testosterone     0.4000000 1e-01  ng/L    1st  2013     finished - WTF NA  NA 1e-04
50  cis-Testosterone     0.0075000 1e-04  µg/L    1st  2011                raw NA  NA    NA
51  cis-Testosterone     0.0055000 1e-04  µg/L    1st  2011     finished - WTF NA  NA    NA
52          Cotinine     0.0010000 1e-03  µg/L    3rd  2018 finished - rechlor NA  NA    NA
53          Cotinine     0.0010000 1e-03  µg/L    4th  2018                raw NA  NA    NA
54          Cotinine     0.0010000 1e-03  µg/L    4th  2018     finished - WTF NA  NA    NA
55          Cotinine    -0.9208188 1e-03  µg/L    1st  2017     finished - WTF NA  NA    NA
56          Cotinine    -0.9208188 1e-03  µg/L    2nd  2017 finished - rechlor NA  NA    NA
57          Cotinine    -1.0969100 1e-03  µg/L    4th  2015 finished - rechlor NA  NA    NA
58          Cotinine    -1.1549020 1e-03  µg/L    3rd  2014 finished - rechlor NA  NA    NA
59          Cotinine    -0.9208188 1e-03  µg/L    1st  2013                raw NA  NA    NA
60          Cotinine    -0.9208188 1e-03  µg/L    2nd  2013     finished - WTF NA  NA    NA
61          Cotinine    -1.2218487 1e-03  µg/L    4th  2013                raw NA  NA    NA
62          Cotinine    -1.2218487 1e-03  µg/L    4th  2013     finished - WTF NA  NA    NA
63          Cotinine    -1.2218487 1e-03  µg/L    1st  2012                raw NA  NA    NA
64          Cotinine    -0.7958800 1e-03  µg/L    1st  2012     finished - WTF NA  NA    NA
65          Cotinine    -1.2218487 1e-03  µg/L    1st  2012 finished - rechlor NA  NA    NA
66          Cotinine    -1.2218487 1e-03  µg/L    2nd  2012                raw NA  NA    NA
67          Cotinine    -1.6989700 1e-03  µg/L    2nd  2012     finished - WTF NA  NA    NA
68          Cotinine    -0.9208188 1e-03  µg/L    2nd  2012 finished - rechlor NA  NA    NA
69          Cotinine    -0.9586073 1e-03  µg/L    3rd  2012                raw NA  NA    NA
70          Cotinine    -0.8239087 1e-03  µg/L    3rd  2012     finished - WTF NA  NA    NA
71          Cotinine    -0.7695511 1e-03  µg/L    3rd  2012 finished - rechlor NA  NA    NA
72          Cotinine    -0.1611509 1e-03  µg/L    4th  2012                raw NA  NA    NA
73          Cotinine    -0.9586073 1e-03  µg/L    4th  2012     finished - WTF NA  NA    NA
74          Cotinine    -0.9586073 1e-03  µg/L    4th  2011                raw NA  NA    NA
75          Cotinine    -1.3979400 1e-03  µg/L    4th  2010                raw NA  NA    NA
76          Cotinine    -0.9208188 1e-03  µg/L    4th  2010     finished - WTF NA  NA    NA
77          Cotinine    -1.0000000 1e-03  µg/L    4th  2010 finished - rechlor NA  NA    NA
78          Cotinine    -1.6989700 1e-03  µg/L    3rd  2009                raw NA  NA    NA
79              DEET    -0.8860566 5e-03  µg/L    1st  2018                raw NA  NA    NA
80              DEET    -1.0457575 5e-03  µg/L    1st  2018     finished - WTF NA  NA    NA
81              DEET    -0.8860566 5e-03  µg/L    1st  2018 finished - rechlor NA  NA    NA
82              DEET    -1.0000000 5e-03  µg/L    2nd  2018                raw NA  NA    NA
83              DEET    -0.8860566 5e-03  µg/L    3rd  2018                raw NA  NA    NA
84              DEET    -2.6989700 5e-03  µg/L  
85              DEET    -2.3979400 5e-03  µg/L   
86              DEET    -2.3979400 5e-03  µg/L   
87              DEET    -2.3010300 5e-03  µg/L    
88              DEET    -2.3010300 5e-03  µg/L 
89              DEET    -2.3010300 5e-03  µg/L   
90              DEET    -0.3979400 5e-03  µg/L    
91              DEET    -2.1249387 5e-03  µg/L    
92              DEET    -2.2596373 5e-03  µg/L    
93              DEET    -3.0000000 5e-03  µg/L    
94              DEET    -3.0000000 5e-03  µg/L  
95              DEET    -3.0000000 5e-03  µg/L    
96              DEET    -3.0000000 5e-03  µg/L   
97              DEET    -3.0000000 5e-03  µg/L    
98              DEET    -3.0000000 5e-03 µg/L2   
99              DEET    -3.0000000 5e-03  µg/L    
100             DEET    -3.0000000 5e-03  µg/L   
 [ reached 'max' / getOption("max.print") -- omitted 275 rows ]
```

I would like the output to show names on the left x axis with the corresponding frequencies on the right y axis.

Comment: Please make your example reproducible. We don't have `B`.

Comment: The formula argument its a transformation of the principal axis. If your provide an example of your data, so we can see the scale of the variables someone can come up with an reprodusible answer.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. Do I need to upload the entire data set? I have put a good chunk on.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the frecuency as a point may not be the best idea. A usefull aproach is to add the count as a text. Here I show you how to do it. I did not use your data, but I simulated an example df with the same names (consider this for future questions).

**Simulated data**

```
B <- data.frame(
  Analyte = sample(x = c("Acesulfame-k", "Atenolol","Cotinine"),
                   prob = c(0.5, 0.25, 0.25), size = 100,
                   replace = TRUE),
  Concentration = rnorm(100, mean = 1, sd = 0.7)
)
```

**Define a function to set the count an position of text**

```
stat_box_data <- function(y, upper_limit = max(B$Concentration) * 1.15) {
    return( 
      data.frame(
        y = 0.95 * upper_limit,
        label = paste('count =', length(y), '\n')
      )
    )
  }
```

**Create your plot**

```
ggplot(data = B, aes(x = Analyte, y = Concentration)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  stat_summary(
    fun.data = stat_box_data, 
    geom = "text", 
    hjust = 0.5,
    vjust = 0.9
  ) +
  coord_flip()
```

**plot**

[image]